# OS X sending mail on command line

Tags: macos, unix, sendmail

I'm a mac user. I see that I can send mails on my command line with **mail** command. However I can't see when and how it was configured.

I checked postfix and sendmail configs but it didn't help.

If I check var/log/mail.log , I can see that mails are relayed to gmail smtp server : gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

So, where is my mail configuration?

Comment: OS X comes pre-configured for many of the popular mail providers.  Open the Mail app and you can configure there.

Comment: I don't currently have any configuration on the Mail app. I removed it months ago, but maybe config comes from there, let me try to understand

Comment: Mail probably stores it in a plist file someplace, probably under `Library`.

Comment: I found a relay server setup, removed lines from the plist file. However I can still send mail from command line